# SSIS using too much memory to load large (40GB+) XML file into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, large-files

I need to load a single large (40GB+) XML file into an SQL Server 2012 database table using SSIS. I'm having problems because SSIS seems to be trying to load the entire document in memory instead of streaming it.

Here's more details of my SSIS package.

I've created an XML Source with the folowing properties:

- Data access mode: XML file from variable (but could be XML File Location)
- Variable name: variable that specifies the XML file path in my computer.
- XSD location: the path to the XSD that defines the XML being read.

The XML structure is simple, with only 3 hierarchical levels:

1. Root element with header information
2. One level defining collections of objects
3. The leaf level defining individual objects (each with a fixed set of fields)

I need to insert one database record per leaf element, repeating fields from the higher hierarchy levels. In other words, I need to flaten the XML hierarchy.

**How can I make SSIS stream load the data, instead of trying to load the entire document in memory?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML source always loads the entire file. It uses `XmlDocument` to do so (last I checked).

The only thing you can do, is to split up the file somehow, then iteratively run each piece through your data flow.

Beyond that, you're looking at creating a custom data source, which is not trivial. It also represents a serious piece of code to maintain.

There may be third-party data sources which can do this. I had to write my own about five years ago.

Comment: Knowing it's not possible to do what I want is helpful, thanks. But it's a bit sad that such a decent ETL system such as SSIS takes such a naive approach to load XML sources. In my opinion, it should provide a streaming approach for reading XML, at least when the user wants to flaten the XML hierarchy.

Comment: It is possible to do, it just doesn't exist in the box, at least, not the SQL Server 2008 box. I don't know if they've improved it in the SQL Server 2012 era, or if someone else has done it, either for free or for money. It wasn't very hard to do, but it's not a simple enhancement (not something you're going to get to work through a Script Component).

Comment: What about [this article](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/01/26/import-wikipedia-articles-into-sql-server-with-ssis/) in which the authors claim they loaded the WikiPedia articles from a 20GB XML file using SSIS? How did they do it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered processing the files in smaller chunks?

I had the same issue before so I created a script component to process that 1 big XML file into 100's of smaller XML Files then do a forloop and iterate on all of the smaller XML Files to process.

To do this you cant use a `StreamReader.ReadLine` because it will still do the same thing, load that very large file so instead of that use `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles` which is a designed class for this scenario.

Have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx

Comment: I'd rather process the single large XML file with SSIS help if possible. If I can't use SSIS, I'll probably write a C# XML parser myself, but that would be a dread. Treating XML files as regular text files (like you are suggesting) is messy and dangerous because there are no guarantees as to where the line breaks are. I once saw a large XML file that had only one line. It was automatically generated by a process that didn't add line breaks. The XML file was still well-formed and all.

Comment: But XML _is_ just a text file. Line breaks are irrelevant - if it's well formed you process it like any other text file with opening and closing tags. You shouldn't even notice the line breaks in your processing tool. Anyway another suggestion is to convert your XML file into a flat file using some kind of XSLT engine... but it might still load the 40G file into memory. If the file is as simple as you say it shouldn't be hard to write a parser that converts it into a standard flat records/fields file and run that into SSIS.

Comment: @ElectricLlama - Processing an XML file as text kinda defeats the purpose of XML, which to me is to simplify parsing (among many other things, of course). But you've got a valid point, given the SSIS limitation. I'll end up parsing the file and dumping a text version with the records and then load it in SSIS. Thanks!

Comment: Based on the contents of your XML file I would say it's being over complicated for the sake of it - It seems like your data suits a flat file rather than a hierarchical (XML) file.

Comment: @ElectricLlama - You're right, but text files are not an option in my case. The file is provided monthly by an external entity and XML is the standard for data transfer in my organization.